# Send push to many devices for pass

Tags: ios6, push-notification, push, apple-push-notifications, passbook

I am doing pushnotification for pass in passbook. Push works, but nothing shows for pushnotification and if update statically by toggling the back of pass, I can get the updated pass. This is the code I use  :

```
<?php


    // Provide the Certificate and Key Data.
    $cert = '../certificates/Certificates.pem';

    $payload = json_encode (array("aps" => ""));
    error_log('payload :'.$payload,0);


    // Create the and config the socket context. 
    $streamContext = stream_context_create ();
    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $cert);
    $password = ''; 

    if (strlen($password))
        stream_context_set_option($tContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $password);


    // Open the Connection to the APNS Server.
    $ConnectAPNS = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

$query1 = mysql_query("select deviceID from registration");
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1);
$deviceID = $row1['deviceID'];

if(!empty($deviceID)){
$query2 = mysql_query("select pushToken from device ");

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){

    $pushToken= $row2['pushToken']; 

    // Compose and pack the push message
    $apns_message = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $pushToken)) . chr(0) . chr(mb_strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    $success = fwrite($ConnectAPNS, $apns_message);

    // Check if we were able to open a socket.
    if ($success)
        error_log(date('d-m-Y hh:ii:ss', time()) . ': APNS Message successfully sent to push token ' . $pushToken, 0);
    else
        error_log(date('d-m-Y hh:ii:ss', time()) . ': Push error:' . $err . ': ' . $errstr);

    error_log('Stream Response: ' . print_r($success, true), 0); 
}
}
    // Close the Connection to the Server.
@socket_close($ConnectAPNS);
fclose ($ConnectAPNS);
include("feedback.php");
?>
`
```

By using this code, may be 30 mns that I can get pushnotification for updated pass ! This is error I get: `May  7 13:33:21 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[21865] : Too many pushes too fast for pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest -- severe rate limiting will apply.

How to push without this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is opening a new connection every time you iterate through your while loop.

Try opening the connection before the loop, write the requests to the socket within the loop, then close the socket at the end of the script.  That will stop you rapidly battering the gateway with several requests in the space of a second.

Comment: What doesn't work?  If you are getting the same error message, it could be because Apple are still throttling you because of your earlier behaviour! You may want to leave it a while, or issue another certificate and try with that (you will need to reissue all the passes again with the new certificate).

Comment: it works , but why it loops 3 times with 2 pushTokens. This is I get in php_error.log : [07-May-2013 12:07:46 Europe/Berlin] 07-05-2013 1212:0707:4646: APNS Message successfully sent to push token 8fdd14fd1b8f317ddd501ce50aefe631e8ceda46bce865ae30e2d1c37ccc060e
[07-May-2013 12:07:46 Europe/Berlin] 07-05-2013 1212:0707:4646: APNS Message successfully sent to push token 43401d1da3132a04f444bb70ccb0c22636a57119aa004dc815a95b61d462c2bb

Comment: Your `select pushToken from device` will select all rows from your device table.  If you have 6 rows, you will send 6 pushes (again if you are sending the same push to the same device token very quickly, Apple are not going to be happy and may close the connection causing your push to fail)

Comment: I just have 2 rows in device table and I don't know why it sends push to same device again ! I just want to send 1 push to 1 device !

Comment: If you want to send to just one device then add a where condition to that select statements to only select the deviceID and push token that you want.  There is nothing above that should be causing the loop, so could be in your feedback.php include.

Comment: I set loop as I have many devices in registration table and I want to send push to all those devices !

Comment: Errm.. didn't you just say you only wanted to send 1 push to 1 device??

Comment: yes, I say that because if I have 2 devices, I will send 2 push to 2 different devices and 1 push for 1 device !

Comment: now I select * from device ! and there 're only 2 push, no error any more !

Comment: I only want to send all serial next !